# How to write html content in excel sheet cell using displaytag ExcelHssfView class

Tags: java, html, excel, apache-poi, displaytag

I want to write html content to a cell in excel using displaytag ExcelHssfView class. Following is my code snippet

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("NewSheet");
sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(3,15,1,20));
HSSFRow xlsRow2 = sheet.createRow(sheet.getMergedRegion(1).getFirstRow());
HSSFCell cell = xlsRow2.createCell(1);
writeCell("Type:<ol><li>Sedan<ul style='list-style-type:disc'></ul></li><li>SUV<ul style='list-style-type:disc'></ul></li><li>Hatchback<ul style='list-style-type:disc'></ul></li></ol>", cell);
```

The problem is that the html content displays as such in the cell with the tags. Is it possible to write the html content properly in the cells?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, Excel is not an Internet Browser and thus does not render HTML itself. Your best chance is to convert the HTML into a RichText object and set that via the corresponding setValue() method.

Comment: yes. you are right. Thanks for looking into it. Please see the solution I posted if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Process the text in java before writing to cell. For example, replace ul tag with \t and unicode for bullet, ie \t\t\t\u2022 which excel recognizes and presents the text in the same way ul tag does in browser.